# If A is invertible and orthogonally diagonalizable, is $A^{-1}$ orthogonally diagonalizable as well?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I know that the answer is yes. Are the reciprocal of the eigenvalues of A the eigenvalues for $A^{-1}$? If the eigenvalues for A are $3$ and $2$, would the eigenvalues for $A^{-1}$ be $1/3$ and $1/2$?

What does it mean when an orthonormal eigenbasis of A is also an orthonormal eigenbasis of $A^{-1}$?

Comment: Do you need a proof of the claim in the title?

Comment: Yes @AhmedHussein

Comment: If $A=MDM^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal and $M=M^T$, can you write down a formula for $A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Let the orthogonal decomposition of $A$ be denoted as $$A = Q^TDQ$$ where $Q$ is orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal. Since A is invertible,
$$A^{-1} = {\left(Q^TDQ\right)}^{-1} = Q^{-1}D^{-1}{(Q^T)}^{-1} = Q^TD^{-1}Q$$ as the transpose of an orthogonal matrix is is its inverse. Now recall that the inverse of a diagonal matrix is simply a diagonal matrix with the reciprocals of each diagonal element (assuming no zeros). For instance 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0 \\
0 & 3 
\end{pmatrix} ^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{3} 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Since $A$ was invertible there will be no zeros on the diagonal of $D,$ so $A^{-1} $ is orthogonally diagonalizable with the same orthogonal matrix, $Q$ as $A$.

Note that in a orthogonal diagonalization, the diagonal elements in $D$ are you eigenvalues and $Q$ is an orthogonal eigenbasis. For more information, read up on [similarity transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).